# PowerPoint 2007 - How to use Application.NewPresentation event handler?

Tags: vba, event-handling, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

so I've found that PowerPoint 2007 does indeed support event handlers on the Application level. For example `Application.NewPresentation` or even `Application.AfterNewPresentation`

It's described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff745073.aspx

But the real question is, how do I use these? Where do I use them?
To tell you my scenario, what I want is to insert dynamic text into a few textboxes. I have the macro code to do this and it's working exactly as I want it to. But I need the macro to fire once a **new presentation is created from a potm template**. And only on that event. Just like it does in Word 2007.

Where do I start? I tried to just create a sub looking like this and saving it as a potm file and open a new presentation based on that template. And nothing happened.

```
Private Sub App_NewPresentation(ByVal Pres As Presentation)
    MsgBox "Running!"
End Sub
```

Edit: It is possible to open any Office 2007 file with an XML editor. I use the Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office and in that I add a Office 2007 Custom UI.XML part following the guide presented here: http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Auto_Open_Code.html

But I run into problems when PowerPoint creates a new presentation based on that template.
Opening the template in itself works just fine. The event handler is there and the code is run beautifully. But a new presentation based on it? No way, the handler is there as well. But it says it cannot find the macro. Even though the macro is in the new presentation as well since I can open Visual Basic Editor and find the macro and then run it. It's just the autopart that doesn't seem to be working like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** way to create an auto macro in PowerPoint VBA is to have your file as an Add-in (.ppa or .ppam - not .pptx/.pptm/.potm/etc). And the way to create it is:

1. Create a class module. At the top
   (after any `Option XXX`), put
   `Public WithEvents App As
   Application` and then put your
   routine above below that.
2. Create a module of any name and put:

   ```
   Dim X As New Class1
   Sub AutoOpen()
       Set X.App = Application
       ''# Code to create new presentation
   End Sub
   ```

Again, this will not work from your requirement of .potm. Another way that you can consider has been depreciated, but it still works, which is to create a Wizard file.

Comment: Are you sure? I know this was the case in PowerPoint 2003. But in 2007 you have the option of editing the XML data of the file itself. That's how I initially created an autostart handler in a potm file.

Anyway, if I were to create an add-in, the add-in would include a class module with Public WithEvents App As Application. And the powerpoint template actually being used is what should include the code block you provide? Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: I don't get it. I created an add-in file which contains the Public WithEvents App As Application. But I cannot reach "App" from anywhere. I mean, I start a new presentation, open Visual Basic Editor and create a new Class Module. In this I put Public WithEvents App As Application on the top. Then I create a new module, but from the same presentation, I cannot reach "App" at all. When typing Dim X as New App, "App" isn't even in the list. This is the same when I try to Dim X as New App from any other presentation as well. I says "Object required"

Comment: Apologies for the mis-coding. The name of your class you created is what you want to use. So if you just created it and there are no other classes, it is probably "Class1". Then just use that. `Dim X As New Class1`. Ive changed the code above to reflect that.

Comment: Can you tell how to create a class module? If I create a Module and paste in "Public WithEvents App As Application", I'd get an error. Is there many kinds of Modules in PowerPoint VBA?

Comment: @Pompair: Go to the "Insert" menu and then choose "Class Module"

Answer (score 0):

The macro in the presentation that was created has no way to run, as the auto_open macro only works with addins. Based on the way you're doing it, you'd have to reload the ribbon to kick the event in your new presentation you want to run.

Comment: I found that I can create an Add-In and put code in that. But at the point that the code from the add-in is run, the code from the template can't run. I mean, I can reach the code and see if it exists, but I can't run it. 

The solution so far is to run all of the code from the add-in itself. And just do a check to see if the template name equals something I want. To make sure the code is only run in the templates I want and not globally.

Comment: You mean even if you use `Application.Run` you can't run the code? Like here: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00403.htm